# Placing Ionic page onto website

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ios-simulator

I would like to showcase a page from my Ionic 3 project onto my website.

I have been trying to copy the rendered html from the simulator with the rendered main.css and placing it onto my website using a [Marvel css device](https://marvelapp.github.io/devices.css/).

It still seems to need hours of finessing to get to what the simulator looks like.

** This is not a clashing of css files. I checked.

Does anyone know an easy way showcase a demo of the app onto the website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just deploy your built code from project's www directory (wrapped in your css Marvel device container) to your web hosting and it should work given that you do not rely on ionic/cordova only functionalities that would not work on a desktop anyway. In the end it is an Angular app.